# Dynamically adding a row to a table in the User Interface

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic, textarea

I am working on an application in **ASP.NET** that requires a table that has each cell as a `TextArea`. The thing is, the number of rows in that table **should be dynamic and a row should be added** with a button's click (say, the button "Add").

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET and I started off with the `GridView` but to no avail. It would help me if someone can tell me where to start for this kind of dynamic addition of a row.

Comment: is this gridview bound to some data source?

Comment: @jason i am not displaying any data from a data source in the grid. I just want to place textareas dynamically which would allow me to add those data entered in the textareas in a database.. each row of the grid (say, 3 textareas) will have to be entered in the database as a row.. same applies for the dynamically added row(s)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for something like this

1. Drop a gridview on your page
2. Make your data entry form & add a row dynamically to the gridview using button click event
3. On form save, read the rows of gridview using a `foreach loop` & save them to database
4. Store the temprary rows using a datatable in `ViewState` to retain values postback

I have added delete functionality as well,
ASPX

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddGridViewRows.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddGridViewRows" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <br />
        First Name :
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Last Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddRows" runat="server" onclick="btnAddRows_Click" 
            Text="Add Rows To Grid" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
            onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class AddGridViewRows : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    DataTable dt = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnAddRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["myData"] == null)
        {
            // Initialize data table if viewstate is null
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SNo", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns[0].AutoIncrement = true;    // Autogenerate serial key column for example
            dt.Columns[0].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        }
        else
            dt = ViewState["myData"] as DataTable;  // Grab datatable from viewstate if its not null

        // Add your data row
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
        dr["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        // Bind your gridview
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        // Save datatable to ViewState
        ViewState["myData"] = dt;
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["myData"] != null)
        {
            dt = ViewState["myData"] as DataTable;
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            ViewState["myData"] = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need some time to see if this works. Thanks for your time anyways :) I will look at how it turns out and get back here if necessary. :)

Comment: @thedarklord7 you can upvote my post if you find it useful, also if it solved your problem you may mark it as answer.

Comment: Yeah I know. But will your answer help me with this:
I have to enter text into `TextArea`s that are placed in each cell of the grid and I want each row to be added in the database as a row in a table. It applies to those rows that I dynamically add with the button click event, too.

Can your answer do that?

Comment: Just drop a textbox inside a gridview template field & add your rows as I am doing right now. On form save, read your gridview rows using a foreach loop. Can you show me what you have tried uptill now?

Comment: I didn't try anything. I just researched what can be done with GridView. I had the opportunity to implement what you suggested in your answer and found that that was not what I wanted. But what you are suggesting in your comment gives hope to me a bit. And its beyond me how the dynamically added textboxes will have their IDs generated?

Comment: @thedarklord7 you have to try your hands at it to get further. Don't worry about IDs, just use a foreach loop & iterate through each row & use FindControl to find each text box.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But still its not what I asked entirely but this led me to where I wanted to go. Thank you :)